# JsonParser Android Error

Tags: java, android, json

I have two login applications with exactly the same code that calls the json parser class. the first one works fine (you can try it from the link, username admin and pass:123) however the second class gives a null pointer exception on the json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
This is the **JsonParser Class:**

```
          package com.example.mysqltest;
          import java.io.BufferedReader;
          import java.io.IOException;
          import java.io.InputStream;
          import java.io.InputStreamReader;
          import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
          import java.util.List;
          import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
          import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
          import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
          import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
          import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
          import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
          import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
          import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
          import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
          import org.json.JSONException;
          import org.json.JSONObject; 
          import android.util.Log; 
          public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

             }
           }
```

**The Working-fine Class:**

```
    package com.example.mysqltest;
                         import android.app.Activity;
                         import android.app.ProgressDialog;
                         import android.content.Intent;
                         import android.os.AsyncTask;
                         import android.os.Bundle;
                         import android.view.View;
                         import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
                         import android.widget.Button;
                         import android.widget.EditText;
                         import android.widget.Toast;
                         import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
                         import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
                         import org.json.JSONException;
                         import org.json.JSONObject;

                         import java.util.ArrayList;
                         import java.util.List;

                         public class Login extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

     // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    //php login script location:




    //testing from a real server:
                         private static final String LOGIN_URL =           "http://www.eshteghel.comlu.com/dbservice/login.php";

    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        //setup input fields
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);


        //setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);

        //register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
            break;
        case R.id.register:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Register.class);
                startActivity(i);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();

            try {

    /*            try {
                    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                    md5.update(password.getBytes(),0,password.length());
                    password = new BigInteger(1,md5.digest()).toString(16);
                    //System.out.println("Signature: "+signature);

                } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                //Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                       LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                //Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    //Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

                    Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, ReadComments.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    //Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

            /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }


}
```

**While the class that gives the null pointer exception:**

```
    package test.example.com.test;
        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
        import android.view.Menu;
        import android.view.MenuItem;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.EditText;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
        import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;


        public class Sign_in extends FragmentActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button btSignUp,btLogin;
    EditText etUser,etPass;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog nDialog;
    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();



    //testing from a real server:

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://www.eshteghel.comlu.com/dbservice/login.php";

    //JSON element ids from repsonse of php script:
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

        etUser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUser);
        etPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);
        btSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btSignUp);
        btLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btLogin);

        btSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
        btLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_sign_in, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void showDialog(){

        ClientDialog cd = new ClientDialog();
        cd.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DialogFragment");
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.btLogin:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;

            case R.id.btSignUp:
                showDialog();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            nDialog = new ProgressDialog(Sign_in.this);
            nDialog.setTitle("Checking Network");
            nDialog.setMessage("Loading..");
            nDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            nDialog.setCancelable(true);
            nDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            String username = etUser.getText().toString();
            String password = etPass.getText().toString();
            try {

                /*try {
                    MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                    md5.update(password.getBytes(),0,password.length());
                    password = new BigInteger(1,md5.digest()).toString(16);
                    //System.out.println("Signature: "+signature);

                } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                //Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                //Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    //Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    Intent i = new Intent(Sign_in.this, Company.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }else{
                    //Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            nDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null){
                Toast.makeText(Sign_in.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Did you test your web service, post your web service response and stack trace of logcat

Comment: Someone has told "Debug is the best friend of Developers!"

Comment: can you just printout the json file from each of the applications. my wild guess is that one of ur class just doesn't get the json

Comment: webservice response: {"success":1,"message":"Login successful!"}

Comment: Try to start activity from onPostExecute instead of doInBackground which is run on out of UI thread.

Comment: the second class is not getting the json int, so it's not enterring the doinbackgorund at all

Comment: use success code in post execute @IbrahimKaraki

Comment: what at line Sign_in.java:161

Comment: // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);